# Fixed size data structure in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I want a data structure(multi-threaded environment) in java that can hold up to a maximum of 'n' elements. If i add (n + 1)th element, then i should replace the oldest element with this new element. I know i can do it by checking for the size in each add() and doing the replace operation at full size. But, i would like to know if there is any data structure in java library for this. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a fixed size array, and add using the index modulo size. This is known as circular array, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) has decent article on the subject.

Basically, you keep track of an index where you should write the next entry, and let that index wrap around at the buffer size, then when you keep writing, you'll overwrite the entries which are oldest.

Something like this:

```
Object[] ring = new Object[32];
int writeIndex = 0;

public void add(Object o) {
  ring[writeIndex % ring.length] = o;
  writeIndex++;
}
```

Comment: @jmg; only if the surrounding environment doesn't account for being multi-threaded (java.util.HashMap will also fail in a multi-threaded environment, if you don't know how to do multi-threading). Either way, it wasn't meant to be copied verbatim, it was meant to show the principle.

Answer (score 2):

this is a Circular Queue and there is no java native class for this. you can look at [ArrayCircularQueue](http://www.scribd.com/doc/14768610/Array-Circular-Queue).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it, depending on your needs, is to wrap a subclass of LinkedHashMap.

```
import java.util.AbstractSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class FixedSizeSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {
    private final LinkedHashMap<E, E> contents;

    FixedSizeSet(final int maxCapacity) {
        contents = new LinkedHashMap<E, E>(maxCapacity * 4 /3, 0.75f, false) {
            @Override
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry<E, E> eldest) {
                return size() == maxCapacity;
            }
        };      
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return contents.keySet().iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return contents.size();
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        boolean hadNull = false;
        if (e == null) {
            hadNull = contents.containsKey(null);
        }
        E previous = contents.put(e, e);
        return e == null ? hadNull : previous != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return contents.containsKey(o);
    }
}
```